# HTML5 Video is not working with AngularJS ng-src tag

Tags: ajax, html, angularjs, html5-video

AngularJS `ng-src` doesn't work with HTML5 Video element in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FsHah/5/

Looking at video element, the src tag is being populated with the correct src uri, but the video doesn't play.

Is this [not supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352) in [AngularJS](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/oaSFYtWInzE), what is the workaround for this?

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372300/angular-js-dynamic-ng-src-not-working-in-1-2-0-rc-2/21307518

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just Create a Filter:

```
app.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function (recordingUrl) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
        };
    }]);
```

In View File:

```
<audio src="{{Your_URL | trustUrl}}" audioplayer controls></audio>
```

Comment: great answer! good to note that the code for a video is actually
`<video controls="controls" name="Video Name" src="{{videoUrl | trustUrl}}"></video>`

Comment: @BenjaminConant Give this guy a medal!  You just saved me my sanity sir!!  And yes props to the original trusted filter.  Great elegant solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? In this example, where/home do you set the actual source? Your example shows using an audio object, but the question was asking about a video object. Is it the same method for both? Also, what is a filter? Thanks.

Comment: @sdd sdei, any chance you can explain what is happening here?

Comment: works like a charm, but please could you provide an explanation?

Answer (score 8):

This currently seems like a bug in AngularJS: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352

Replacing source with `<video ng-src="{{src}}" controls></video>` seems to be the only way at the moment to at least load a source into the video. Hopefully someone comes around to either fix this or provide a workaround of some sort.

Comment: it took my whole day but this solution does the trick.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

To play the video I just used the following method
have a button called play and in the  ng-click of the button you have to write this

```
 var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
myVideo.src = vidURL;
myVideo.load();
myVideo.play();
```

to play video in ng-repeat use *index*.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you, this worked for me! In my situation, I wanted the video to play automatically, so I did it this way using a JS timeout.

Answer (score 5):

Remove source tag from video tag and try this..

```
<video controls preload=auto ng-src="{{videoURL| trustUrl}}" poster="{{thumbnailUrl}}"></video>
```

and in your angular app create a filter like this

```
 app.filter("trustUrl", function($sce) {
            return function(Url) {
                console.log(Url);
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(Url);
            };
        });
```

Comment: note: poster will be an error "Not Found", should be ng-attr-poster

Answer (score 4):

My response is a few years late, but this is for anyone who is still looking for a solution. I had the same issue. I remembered that Youtube displays their embedded videos using a different tag - iframe.
I applied the properties I wanted and it worked.

`<iframe width="560" height="300" ng-src="{{ video }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls></iframe>`

For anyone new to AngularJS, the {{ video }} is a $scope.video variable in the control for this page that has the path to the video.

Answer (score 2):

workaround

in controller

```
$scope.mp3 = "http://download.jw.org/audio.mp3"

$scope.$watch('mp3', function() {
       $("audio").attr("src",$scope.mp3)
   });
```

html:

```
<audio id="mejs" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

Comment: angular equivalent, without jQuery dependency:  `angular.element(document.getElementById('audio_element_id')).attr('src', $scope.mp3)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a default security precaution in AngularJS. Please see the details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

To disable the 'Strict Contextual Escaping' compeletly you can define this in your app.js file

```
angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
      // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
      // Do not use in new projects.
      $sceProvider.enabled(false);
    });
```

However they don't recommend. But you may use for a spesific controller like this:

```
var myAppControllers = angular.module('myAppControllers', []); ScorpAppControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Home',    function ($scope, Home) {
$scope.Home = Home.query(); }]).config(function($sceProvider) {
$sceProvider.enabled(false); });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening is Angular fills in the `src` attributes after the  and  elements have been added to the page, so the browser sees the elements with broken URLs. I worked around it using `ng-if`:

```
        <video muted ng-if="foo" loop autoplay>
            <source ng-src="{{foo.media.mp4.url}}">
            <source ng-src="{{foo.media.webm.url}}" type="video/webm">
            <img ng-src="{{foo.media.gif.url}}">
        </video>
```

This makes the  element tied to the existence of `foo`, which is a scope variable being populated via AJAX call.

Comment: Put the `ngIf` in each `source` element and check if the `ngSrc` value is indeed set: `<source ng-src="{{foo.media.mp4.url}}" ng-if="!!foo.media.mp4.url">` This should work as well, and you don't need to maintain an additional `foo` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-media](https://github.com/caitp/ng-media) module.

```js
angular.module('app', ['media'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
        
        $scope.videoSources = [];
        
        $scope.loadVideos = function() {
            $scope.videoSources.push('http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4');
            $scope.videoSources.push('http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.webm');
        };
    });
```

```html
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='mainCtrl'>        
    <video html5-video='{{ videoSources }}'
        autoplay='true' controls='true'>
    </video>
    <br>
    <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://caitp.github.io/ng-media/ng-media.js"></script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G6LReT).

Answer (score 0):

Just use vanilla js (regular javascript) to make this work.
If you are listening to events like onended you might want to reconsider using $scope.$apply().

My example:

```
document.getElementById('video').src = $scope.videos[$scope.videoindex];
```