# Unable to fill in variable in video src using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS, and have the following template:

```
<view title="'Watch ' + movie.title">
  <content has-header="true" padding="true">
    <video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
      <source src="video/{{ movie.id }}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </content>
</view>
```

When I try and run it I get the error `Error while interpolating: video/{{ movie.id }}.mp4
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required`. However, I have no problems putting `{{ movie.id }}` as text below in a button or anything else, so what's wrong?

Comment: I googled that error and found this: [Angular JS dynamic ng-src not working in 1.2.0-rc.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372300/angular-js-dynamic-ng-src-not-working-in-1-2-0-rc-2) - Ignore the marked answer and look at the most upvoted one instead, it explains the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `ng-src` directive here:
`ng-src="video/{{ movie.id }}.mp4"`
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: can you show an example in plunker? Maybe you should use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`?
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/service/$sce
e.g. `videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('video/'+movie.id);`

Answer (score 0):

A work around could be

```
ng-init="myurl = movie.id + '.mp4'"
```