# HTML5 video downloaded twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I had angular directive that appended `video element` into html something like this

```
elem.append("<video " + "src='" + scope.MediaURL + "' type='video/" + type + "'"></video>")
```

I have now moved to use `templateUrl` and there I have video element like this:

```
<video controls preload="metadata" autoplay ng-src="{{mediaUrl | trustUrl}}"></video>
```

`trustUrl` is filter I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag) because of the same problem.

But the problem is that now the video is downloaded twice. And I can't figure out why. Could it because of the filter?
[image]

EDIT: I don't think it's because of the filter, because without it, the error is thrown twice.

EDIT2: I need to provide more details. The template has both `video` and `img` elements. Only one is shown depending on what type of media is in `mediaUrl`. So it looks like this:

```
<video ng-if="mediaType == 'video'"></video>
<img ng-if="mediaType == 'image'" />
```

The video is downloaded twice only the first time `video` element is shown. So if the `mediaType` is image and is changed to video, it will be downloaded twice. If I then change url which also has video, it will be downloaded once. If I change url back to image and then back to video, it will be downloaded twice again and so on.