# Video does not play when device audio is playing and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

So when my video loads and begins to play, the audio from the device (ipod, spotify) stops playing. If I force the audio to play (by switching over to ipod and pressing play and combing back to my app) the video is frozen. I also tested out an audio file directly in the app and that works perfectly fine while the video is playing. The audio works all through out the app and I placed it in the same UIView as the video. All videos in the app do not have any audio files. I have tried the "muted" preference in the video tag with no luck. This is an essential part of the app and any help would be really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div style="height:85%;width:100%;border:0px solid purple;border-radius:100px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0%;" ng-click="showIt();" on-swipe-right="prev()" on-swipe-left="next()">

    <video webkit-playsinline muted autoplay loop ng-src="{{keeper}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px solid white;border-radius:100px;z-index:1;">
    </video>

</div>
```

I am willing to try anything, so please feel free to throw out any ideas you may have.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag You have to create a filter for your audio

Comment: this was a listed issue (now closed) in angular. There's a list of SO questions with answers and an official workaround from angular here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352

Comment: @RachelGallen the video files are .mp4 files with no audio (i edited them in premiere pro). They are exercise videos (3-4 seconds each) looped over and over to demonstrate different exercise moves..I'm going to try that filter and let you know...Thanks:)

Comment: @RachelGallen BTW this app is built on ionic framework and intended for iOS and Andriod app

Comment: hope it works! :) .. yeah i know, i noticed. but still, the filter should help

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from [ThePolyGlotDeveloper.com](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/)

```
ionic start IonicProject blank
cd IonicProject
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add ios
```

Install Apache Cordova Media PluginShell

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter">
   //important to note that ng-cordova.min.js must come before cordova.js in your script includes.  Your project will not work correctly if it comes after.


    app.js

     angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Create a new controller like so:

app.js

```
example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.play = function(src) {
        var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
        $cordovaMedia.play(media);
    }

    var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Play from a url (index.html)

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <button class="button" ng-click="play('http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2013.mp3')">Play from internet</button>
</ion-content>
```

or a local file (index.html file):

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <button class="button" ng-click="play('www/mp3/song.mp3')">Play from file system</button>
</ion-content>
```

Watch the [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/Oflc5d8d_O4)

[Code Source](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/)