# Getting error with poster attribute in <video> in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following code:

```
<div class="item item-input video-preview-container" ng-if="thumbnail.length > 0">
                <video poster="{{thumbnail}}" ng-src="{{clipSrc}}" class="centerme margin-vert-2x" controls="controls" preload="metadata" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline"></video>
                <i class="ion ion-android-cancel fs30 margin-left-2x" ng-click="removeVideo()"></i>
            </div>
```

now on running this i am getting error:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/%7B%7Bthumbnail%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

however it is noticeable that the error is coming when my div isn't yet loaded as my `ng-if` condition is still `less than 0`

UPDATE: the problem is with `poster="{{thumbnail}}"` code as when i remove this the error is not coming.

Comment: remove the "==true" part and try with just `ng-if="thumbnail.length"`

Comment: actually it was mistypes the actual condition is `ng-if="thumbnail.length>0"`

Comment: Could you please add more code, maybe a controller?

Comment: Where do you insert the URL? I can't find this in your example.

Comment: Instead of ng-if use ng-show. That way your div will reside in the DOM. Also can you confirm if the image URL (http://localhost:8100/%7B%7Bthumbnail%7D%7D) is correct.

Comment: urls are in the controller.....what i am saying here is that the <video> is not loaded in my view but still i am getting error from this part of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag

Comment: the problem is not with ng-src ..i have updated the question.

Comment: It is a good idea to sanitize the URL

Comment: The problem is while interpolation of the thumbnail variable passed to the poster attribute. %7B and %7D you notice in the url are code for {{ and }}

Comment: Try making a  directive like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/mgosw7kx/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using `ng-attr-poster` ? Most of time these problems are due to data binding not happening

Comment: yeah maybe I have to interpolate my poster attribute