# Set video source from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set the video source from the controller. If I hard coded the source everything works fine. But if I try to set it in the server doesn't work.

```
<video id="myVideo"  style="width:100%">
<source src="../../../../Content/Videos/{{$ctrl.videoSource}}"> - Doesn'tWork
<source src="../../../../Content/Videos/Test1.mp4">
```

```
self.videoSource = data.videoLink;
```

Comment: use ng-src instead of src in attribute

Comment: Still doesn't work ,I used <source ng-src="../../../../Content/Videos/SetVideos/{{$ctrl.videoSource}}">

Comment: actually you gotta do something like

ng-src="$ctrl.getSource()" where getSource method would return the app src

Comment: Would you care tell us if one of the answer worked? I wrote down the answer as well there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
ng-src="$ctrl.getSource()"
```

and

in controller :

```
getSource() { return '../../../../Content/Videos/' + this.videoSource; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `ng-src` attribute on the `<video>` tag.

I know there used to be a bug in AngularJS where `ng-src` didn't work for `<video>` tags. 
If that is still the case, you can always write a custom filter to trust the URL.
See: [HTML5 Video is not working with AngularJS ng-src tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag)