# ng-if is not display data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have images and videos dynamically but I want to display images or videos at a time.
I want to that When i click on images id then it will show images and when i click on video Id then it will show video.

html code:

```
<div class="container" ng-init="image()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="img in images">                    
                <div class="mySlides" > 
                    <div class="numbertext">{{img.id}}</div>
                    <img class="size-i" ng-src="{{img.oe_images}}" ng-show="isActive($index)" ng-if="img.type == 'image'" type="image"style="width:100%;">
                </div>
                <video ng-if="img.type == 'video'" type="video"width="100%" ng-click="video()" id="video" controls="controls" ng-show="isActive($index)">
                    <source src="./assets/vdo/{{img.oe_images}}" type="video"type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <a class="prev" ng-click="showPrev()"style="font-size:36px;" >❮</a>
                    <a class="next" ng-click="showNext()"style="font-size:36px;" >❯</a> 
                    <div class="row paddi" >
                        <div class="column" ng-repeat="img in images">
                            <img class="demo cursor border-demo" ng-src="{{img.oe_images}}" ng-if="img.type == 'image'" type="image"ng-show="isActive($index)"style="width:100%; display: block !important;" data="{{img.id}}" ng-click="currentSlide(img.id)" alt="{{img.oe_images}}" type="image">
                        </div>
                        <video ng-if="img.type == 'video'" type="video" controls="controls" src="./assets/vdo/{{img.oe_images}}" type="video/mp4" ng-show="isActive($index)"style="width:100%"></video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here i am using ng-if to display images or Video at a time but after using ng-if no data diplay. Please tell what is my mistake.
thank you in advance

Comment: can you post the structure of an `img` object please?
Also check what the condition `img.type == 'video'` and `img.type == 'image'` prints in each case

Comment: Sir, When i click on images id then it will show images and when i click on video then it will show video. I want to just like that

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap `<video>`s into `<div>` containers and apply `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` to containers not `<video>`s:

```
<div ng-show='condition1'>
     <video id='video1'/>
</div>
<div ng-show='condition2'>
     <video id='video2'/>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain to me how I will use this

Comment: want to that When i click on images id then it will show images and when i click on video Id then it will show video.

Comment: @MohammadFareed, try to change `ng-if` to `ng-show` to preserve corresponding html(data as you wrote).

Comment: Sir, only images id display all images but when i click on video id then videos is not display

Comment: @MohammadFareed, specify location of ng-click directive and videos to show and javascript code.

Comment: when i have put ng-if on videos section then it displays

Answer (score -1):

Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728424/html5-video-is-not-working-with-angularjs-ng-src-tag). Look the first answer about **trustAsResourceUrl**. 
Perhaps, it will resolve your issue.

```
app.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
    };
}]);
```

In HTML - view file:

```
<video src="{{ Your_URL | trustUrl }}" videoplayer controls></video>
```

Comment: sir, this is for videos issues but want to that When i click on images id then it will show images and when i click on video Id then it will show video.